# Show that $10n^2-15n+2016 = \Omega(n^2)$ by definition

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

### Task

Show that $10n^2-15n+2016 = \Omega(n^2)$ by definition

### Attempt to show

By definition statement is true if $\exists c, n_0$ so that

$$ 10n^2-15n+ 2016 \ge c n^2 , \text{ when } n \ge n_0$$

Let $c = 1, n_0 = 0$, then we have

$$ 9n^2 - 15n + 2016 \ge 0, \text{ when } n\ge 0$$

which holds because

$$ (-15)^2-4\cdot 2016 < 0 $$

---

Is this correct?

Comment: $\sqrt{(-15)^2-4\cdot 2016}$ is not smaller than $0$. However, it is true that $9n^2-15n+2016>0$ for all $n\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Edited the post, now it should be right

Comment: Now it is.${}{}$

Comment: I would add that the expression is positive when $n=0$.  Then your calculation shows it's positive for all $n$.